# Styling span textnode without styling child nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

So I'm creating a theme plugin for a forum where users often enter text with custom coloring. This is implemented as an inline style on a span.

The forum by default has a dark color scheme so most of the text is light.  If I create a theme with a light color scheme this text would be hard to see.

I thought of using a CSS5 color filter that targets text with inline colors:

```
.Comment span[style^=color] {
   filter: hue-rotate(180deg) invert(100%);
   -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg) invert(100%);
}
```

By inverting and rotating the color spectrum this turns a light blue color into a dark blue and light red into dark red, preserving the hue but making it darker.  This actually works but it has the side effect of also inverting the colors of images and other elements embedded in the text.

I thought of doing another color inversion on child elements but this leaves images looking like junk since apparently hue-rotate is not very accurate at all.

A solution would be to have the CSS only target the text node of the span and not any child elements but that does not seem possible?  Unless I'm missing something I don't see any selectors for text nodes.

Is there something I can do in jQuery to perform this color inversion?  I'd rather not have to destroy all the coloring on the page as that would upset the users.

Comment: Interesting. With small rotations there is no problem. http://jsfiddle.net/urqqbz23/

Comment: That's a nice demonstration of how hue rotate is not reversible but note it only works in firefox.  The effect is much worse with images.

Answer (score 0):

## this Solution only goes lighter does not solve the problem:

I mis-read the question... I tried to delete this because it did not solve the problem for light backgrounds but it still appeared.

This can be accomplished by making use of `rgba`

Tested and works:

```
$(window).load(function() {
      var col = $('.Comment').css('color').replace(')', ', 0.20)').replace('rgb', 'rgba');
      $('.Comment').css('color', col);    
});
```

`var col` converts `rgb` to `rgba` allowing for color percentage

Comment: Doesn't that just lower the opacity?  The problem is to make light text on a light background easier to see while preserving hue.

Comment: I believe you are right regarding opacity. As edited, I tried to delete the solution because it only did the opposite of your need. It only left it disabled so I turn it back on. On my site I am running a PHP function that would meet your need but it works with hex and jquery converts to rgb. I'd happy to post it if you would like to take a look see.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses the javascript library tinycolor.  A pure CSS solution would be much preferred but it doesn't seem possible.

```
$.getScript('https://rawgit.com/bgrins/TinyColor/master/tinycolor.js').done( function() {
    $('.Comment span[style^=color]').each(function() {
        var color = tinycolor($(this).css('color')).toHsl();
        color.l = 1 - color.l;
        $(this).css({'color': tinycolor(color).toRgbString()});
    });
});
```